# unexpected result when I create responsive nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create responsive nav bar like [this](https://uicookies.com/demo/theme/landing/)

my code works when show and hide the nav items but it doesn't change the bars icon

no console errors or warns

my html:

```
<nav>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="logo">Landing</div>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="item">Home</li>
                        <li class="item">Features</li>
                        <li class="item">Reviews</li>
                        <li class="item">Pricing</li>
                        <li class="item">FAQ</li>
                        <li class="item">Get Started</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    nav .toggle {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: right;
        order: 2;
        display: block;
    }
    nav .item {
        order: 2;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
    }
    .active-menu .item {
        display: block;
    }
    }
```

and jquery:

```
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
function toggleMenu(){
    if($(menu).hasClass('active-menu')){
        $(menu).removeClass('active-menu');
        $(toggle).has('a').html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>');
    } else {
        $(menu).addClass('active-menu');
        $(toggle).has('a').html('<i class=\'fa fa-times\'></i>');
    }
}
$(toggle).click(toggleMenu)
```

the nav has a flex display

I couldn't publish it on github cuz I am not familiar with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you overwrite `<a>..</a>` with `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>`. Then `$(toggle).has('a')` return null so the HTML of your `toggle` element remains unchanged. To fix this, why don't you just change the class of your `<i></i>` element like so:

```
const toggle = $(".toggle");
const menu = $(".menu");
function toggleMenu(){
    if(menu.hasClass('active-menu')){
        menu.removeClass('active-menu');
        toggle.find('i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-bars');
    } else {
        menu.addClass('active-menu');
        toggle.find('i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-times');
    }
}
toggle.click(toggleMenu)
```

Note that you may simplify

```
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
$(toggle)...
```

with

`const toggle = $(".toggle");`

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/t8gfbhyq/